# Warning: Task "webTest" not found

Tags: gruntjs

I cannot figure out why I cannot register these two tests in one Gruntfile. when I run `grunt test`, it runs perfectly fine. When I run `grunt web`, it gives me `Warning: Task "webTest" not found`. The code within each task is exactly the same, so why if grunt only allowing one task to register?

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt){
  // Load grunt mocha task
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // webTest
    webTest: {
          test: {
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['all.js',
                        'test/groups.js',
                        'test/doctors.js',
                        'test/patients.js',
                        'test/diet.js']
          }
        },

    // Mocha Test
    mochaTest: {
          test: {
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['all.js',
                        'test/groups.js',
                        'test/doctors.js',
                        'test/patients.js',
                        'test/diet.js']
          }
        }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('web', ['webTest']);
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['mochaTest']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt){
  // Load grunt mocha task
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Mocha Test
    mochaTest: {
          test: {
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['test/groups.js',
                        'test/doctors.js',
                        'test/patients.js',
                        'test/diet.js']
          },
          web_enter: { // fill database for website testing
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['test/web_testing_enter.js']
          },
          web_remove: { // remove data entered for website testing
            options: {
              reporter: 'list',
              timeout: 2000
            },
            src: ['test/web_testing_remove.js']
          }
        }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('we', ['mochaTest:web_enter']);
  grunt.registerTask('wr', ['mochaTest:web_remove']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['mochaTest:test']);
};
```